# Why does R treat a list as a matrix in the following example?

Tags: r

Why does this code return class == 'matrix'?

```
l = lapply(1:25, function(x)x)
attr(l,"dim") = c(5,5)
class(l)
```

The following code then crashes:

```
image(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to `?attr`

> attr(x, which) <- value
>
> which - a non-empty character string specifying which attribute is to be accessed.

So we need

```
attr(l, 'dim') <- c(5, 5)
```

---

Other options include

```
m1 <- matrix(l, 5, 5)
```

Or assign with `dim`

```
dim(l) <- c(5, 5)

class(m1)
#[1] "matrix"
str(m1)
#List of 25
# $ : int 1
# $ : int 2
# $ : int 3
# $ : int 4
# ...

identical(m1, l)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Regarding the `matrix` with `list` elements, `l` is a `list` of vector with `length`.  For extracting the element, we need `[[`.  Here, we are directly adding a `dim` attribute to 'l' to coerce it to `matrix` with `matrix` resulting in each element of `matrix` a `list` of `length` 1. `matrix` have row/column attributes which separate it from the `vector`.  By assigning that, we are changing the `list` with `row/column` attributes to make it a `matrix`

In effect, the `list` structure is not lost by adding `dim`ensions.  If we need to change the `list` to a `vector`, `unlist` to a `vector` and then do the `dim` or `matrix` call

```
matrix(unlist(l), 5, 5)
```

Comment: My first question regarded the class function. Why does it return class == 'matrix' if we set dimnames to a list? Does any object with dimnames classifisy as a matrix?

sapply(l, class) shows that all elements of l are integer, not list

Comment: I believe the real problem is that they have a matrix of mode list. `image.default` tests `is.list(x)` first and treats it as a list then. That fails because the list does not contain `z` and `z` was also not supplied as a parameter.

Comment: @user680111 A matrix is a vector with a dimension attribute. A list is a vector (but not an atomic vector).

Comment: @user680111. `sapply` is looping through individual elements of `list` and thoes elements are `integer` class